# JQuery animate and open div when clicking on trigger and close on same button

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have a piece of HTML that I want to when clicked animate the div and close when clicked again. HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="menu_greyed performance_menu_trigger">My Details <span class="push_right">&#x25BC;</span></a>
<div class="performance_menu_holder">
<a href="details" class="push_right performance_menu_item">Details</a>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.performance_menu_holder').hide()
        $('.performance_menu_trigger').click(function(){
            $('.performance_menu_holder').animate({ "opacity" : "show", bottom: "100" }, 500);
            $('.performance_menu_trigger').addClass('performance_menu_trigger_close');
        });
        $('.performance_menu_trigger_close').click(function(){
            $('.performance_menu_holder').animate({ "opacity" : "show", top: "100" }, 500);
            $('.performance_menu_trigger').removeClass('performance_menu_trigger_close');
        });
    });
```

It opens as it should when you click it for the first time, but not when it's open. It doesn't close the div.

Comment: Why not click `<>` and create a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.performance_menu_holder').hide()
        $('.performance_menu_trigger').click(function(){
            $('.performance_menu_holder').slideToggle({ "opacity" : "show", bottom: "100" }, 500);
            $('.performance_menu_trigger').addClass('performance_menu_trigger_close');
        });
        $('.performance_menu_trigger_close').click(function(){
            $('.performance_menu_holder').slideToggle({ "opacity" : "show", top: "100" }, 500);
            $('.performance_menu_trigger').removeClass('performance_menu_trigger_close');
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="menu_greyed performance_menu_trigger">My Details <span class="push_right">&#x25BC;</span></a>
<div class="performance_menu_holder">
<a href="details" class="push_right performance_menu_item">Details</a>
</div>
```

You can using slideToggle instead of animation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.performance_menu_holder').hide()
    $('.performance_menu_trigger').click(function(){
        $('.performance_menu_holder').slideToggle({ "opacity" : "show", 
bottom: "100" }, 500);

$('.performance_menu_trigger').addClass('performance_menu_trigger_close');
    });
    $('.performance_menu_trigger_close').click(function(){
        $('.performance_menu_holder').slideToggle({ "opacity" : "show", top: "100" }, 500);
        $('.performance_menu_trigger').removeClass('performance_menu_trigger_close');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have achived it with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.performance_menu_holder').hide()
        $('.performance_menu_trigger').click(function(){
            $('.performance_menu_holder').slideToggle("fast");
        });
    });
```